# iOS 5 - navigation and tab bar not appear after presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

i am developing an ios app and using storyboards generally. in my view controller named blackView (it has no xib file) there is a button to play video. that button goes to another view controller named videoViewController (videoViewController is not in storyboard it has xib file). after user clicks to done on the videoViewController user should return to the blackView and now all is work but after return to the blackView from videViewController the navigation bar and tab bar controllers of blackView not appear

how can i handle this? how can i get appear those navigation and tab bars on the blackView?

this is my code in my videoViewController.m file

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController * myview=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"blackView"];
    [self presentModalViewController:myview animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: try adding `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` in your `blackView`'s view will appear.

Comment: can you try NSLogging if this method gets called at all? if not, you can try calling `[blackView.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` when dismissing modal viewcontroller - ofcourse you'll need some kind of reference to blackView

Comment: i put nslog just under the [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; in blackview.m's viewWillAppear method and the nslog works but navigation controller not appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code i thing you are doing something wrong.

i need to ask one question to you that movieplayer in is presented od added as subview.

if you are presenting it then you need to do something like this in youe app.

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Comment: thank you so much. that's it! dismissModalViewController solves my problem. yesterday all day i looked for that